# Is there any limit of data while tcp transfering between Client-server?

Tags: c++, tcp, winsock2

I want to transfer 32k data between client-server with WinSock2. Is it possible or there is a limitation with data?

Comment: TCP is a stream, you can send as much data as you want, though any individual call to `send()` or `WSASend()` has a max buffer size of `MaxInt` (2147483647) or `MaxUlong` (4294967295) bytes per send, respectively, but you can call them multiple times per connection.

Answer (score 3):

"I want to transfer 32k data between client-server with WinSock2. Is it possible" - Yes.

32K is *tiny*. If you had asked about 2^32 or 2^64 bits of data, then you may have a situation where you could run into trouble. But 32K? No.

Also; Why didn't you just *try*? A simple test program would have shown you i 5min that transfering 32K of data is not a problem at all. Please make a minimal effort before asking a question.